# Unable to edit a mysql subject using Php

Tags: php, mysql, edit

So I'm creating this CMS for faculty information as part of my thesis. When I need to create/delete a subject, my code seems to be working fine. However, when I try to update them, it tells me that the editing process failed. Not sure where exactly it's going wrong.

Below is my subject query. I'm sort of new at php so if i've made some glaring errors, bear with me.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//form was submitted
    $staff_id = mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_POST["staff_id"]);
    $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]);
    $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["last_name"]);
    $age   = mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_POST["age"]);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $phone_no = mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_POST["phone_no"]);
    $department = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["department"]);
    $visible = mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_POST["visible"]);   
    $message = "Your details have been received";

    //Database Query
    $query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
    $query .= "first_name = '{$first_name}', ";
    $query .= "last_name = '{$last_name}', ";
    $query .= "age = '{$age}', ";
    $query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
    $query .= "phone_no = '{$phone_no}', ";
    $query .= "department = '{$department}', ";
    $query .= "visible = '{$visible}', ";
    $query .= "WHERE staff_id = '{$staff_id}', ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1)
        {
            //Success
            echo "Subject Edited. ";
        }
    else
        {
            //failure
            echo "Subject Editing failed. ";
        }
}
```

and this is the form that's used to send the data for editing

```
<form action="editsub.php" method ="post">
            <p>Staff ID to edit:
                <input type="number" name="staff_id" value ="" />   
            </p> 
            <p>First Name:
                <input type="text" name="first_name" value ="" />                   
            </p>
            <p>Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value ="" />                    
            </p>
            <p>Age:
                <input type="number" name="age" value ="" />    
            </p>
            <p>E-mail:
                <input type="text" name="email" value ="" />    
            </p>
            <p>Phone Number:
                <input type="number" name="phone_no" value ="" />   
            </p>
            <p>Department:
                <input type="text" name="department" value ="" />   
            </p>
            <p>Visible:
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value ="0" /> No &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value ="1" /> Yes
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Entry" />
            </form>
```

So if someone could point out where the error is I'd be much obliged. thanks

Comment: What does the error reporting kick out? http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php (`echo mysqli_error($connect);`)

Comment: You have an unnecessary comma in your where clause.

Comment: @AnthonySterling you should add this as an answer rather than a comment. (Good eye :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed it - change:

```
$query .= "visible = '{$visible}', ";
$query .= "WHERE staff_id = '{$staff_id}', ";
```

to:

```
$query .= "visible = '{$visible}'";
$query .= "WHERE staff_id = '{$staff_id}'";
```

i.e: incorrect commas

Comment: You are a life saver. I can't believe it was that simple. #facepalm thanks luckypoon and anthony sterling

Comment: Upvotes and accepts are appreciated for my Rep collection :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

this code here

```
    //Database Query
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "first_name = '{$first_name}', ";
$query .= "last_name = '{$last_name}', ";
$query .= "age = '{$age}', ";
$query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
$query .= "phone_no = '{$phone_no}', ";
$query .= "department = '{$department}', ";
$query .= "visible = '{$visible}', ";
$query .= "WHERE staff_id = '{$staff_id}', ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Should be like this

```
//Database Query
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "first_name = '$first_name', ";
$query .= "last_name = '$last_name', ";
$query .= "age = '$age', ";
$query .= "email = '$email', ";
$query .= "phone_no = '$phone_no', ";
$query .= "department = '$department', ";
$query .= "visible = '$visible' ";
$query .= "WHERE staff_id = '$staff_id' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong. You have a "," before "WHERE" and also before "LIMIT". Delete both "," and try again.